# Is there an analogue of theta cycles for more general mod p automorphic forms?

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

The theory of $\theta$-cycles (due to Tate, I think) and filtrations is to me a very beautiful and powerful tool in proving many statements about mod $p$ modular forms in more explicit and elementary manner. Is there an analogue of $\theta$-cycles for mod $p$ automorphic forms of higher rank groups? If so, is there any occasion where such theory is used in proving some interesting statements?